# Model class 'AnnotationModel' from module 'ipyannotate' is loaded but can not be instantiated

Tags: python

I am trying to work with the MapReader module in Jupyter Notebook.
https://mapreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/User-guide/Download.html

There is the code I'm using :

```
from mapreader import loader
from mapreader.annotate.utils import prepare_annotation

test_map = loader("/Users/robinrose/MapReader-main/maps/carte_ile_manga-reva.png")

test_map.patchify_all(patch_size=200)
parent_list = test_map.list_parents()
patch_list = test_map.list_patches()
#test_map.show(patch_list[250:300])


annotation = prepare_annotation(
    userID="rose",
    annotation_tasks_file="/Users/robinrose/MapReader-main/annotation_tasks.yaml",
    task="hute",
    annotation_set="set_001",
  )
```

There is the Javascript error :

[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Model class 'AnnotationModel' from module 'ipyannotate' is loaded but can not be instantiated
@http://localhost:8889/nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets/extension.js:2:780075

I already tried to downgrade Jupyter notebook to 5.7.5 as I saw it worked for other modules but here it didn't.
I tried to import directly ipyannotate.